# Send messages between Uinx pc-s in different networks and access these by python

Tags: gratis, python, chat, communication, unix

Is there a free (of cost) software (chat, some API etc.) which allows me to send non-encrypted text messages from one Unix pc to another and read in these messages by a python script? The 2 pc-s can be in arbitrary and different networks, so things like ssh and port forwarding do not work.
PS: If it is a chat it should be one which does not require phone number. Email address is ok.

Comment: If it's not about sensible information which should be properly encrypted, IRC comes to mind.

Comment: Do I need to set up my own server or are there some public ones which I could use?

Comment: Loads of public servers. Most well known is probably freenode. For more details, see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Relay_Chat